# How to add dynamic content to head.additional in magento2?

Tags: magento2, blocks

It is required to show dynamic javascript `userId` var in head.additional block if the user is logged in, otherwise `null`.

So I am injecting my block into `default` layout handle

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
                <block class="Test\Test\Block\Head" name="testtest_head" />
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

in the block, I use this code and it works great

```
class Head extends Template
{
  ...
     protected function _afterToHtml($html)
     {
          return $html. $this->getMyUserIdCode();
     }

}
```

But when I enable the cache, `userId` won't refresh even if customer logged in. How can I properly avoid caching in this sutuation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to create helper for this.

File Path:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php

Code:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    private $httpContext;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()    
    {
        $isLoggedIn = $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
        return $isLoggedIn;
    }
}
```

And this you can reference in your phtml file.